# Add extra row (or row-like block) after row to a table, but within the <tr>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm looking for a way to do something that ends up looking like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>baar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">foobar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but actually is

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>baar</td>
    <td class="fakerow">foobar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a not-too-hacky way to do this?

- I'd like to keep the columns aligned.
- I understand the naive choices for any correct markup are limited. <strike>`<tr><div>`</strike>
- I'm injecting the new cell/row via JavaScript and I'd like to keep it nested to allow sorting and styling.
- Preferably by CSS only.
- Preferably the new row has no fixed height.

I have tried something like

```
<tr style="position: relative; padding-bottom: …">
  …
  <td style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: …">
```

but it turned into insanity before anything even started working.
Couldn't do it via `flex` (essentially overriding all `display: table-*` styles) either without messing up columns.
[Fiddle with my failed attempts](http://jsfiddle.net/8mu23hav/).
Maybe `grid`? I'm not up to speed yet.

Comment: That's not how tables work. Why are you using a table for this? If you really have tabular data, what would this new fakerow contain and how does it fit with the column descriptors in the `thead`?

Comment: The `table` is not my choice and I can't change it. From a plugin, I am injecting extra markup (interactive controls and such) to each row. I know that this is not semantically correct.

Comment: ...on the other hand, this *is* just another column, just displayed differently (maybe `fakerow` is misleading. N.b. that I used the first code block just to illustrate the desired layout), so it could have a column descriptor (that might be displayed in the same fashion). I have seen reponsive/mobile layouts for tables that look like "lists of vertical lists" (they usually hide the `thead` and use visual hints to separate the rows).